# Opening my big files: all sheets are made visible every time?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I upgraded recently to a new 64bit Windows PC, on which I have Excel 2010. The following has now unfortunately started happening when I open two of my larger files (with lots of VBA behind them): All of their sheets are automatically made visible by Excel, when they open. But I want these sheets to stay hidden.

It looks like Excel is perhaps trying to recalculate the whole file. But I don't know why it would then need all sheets to be visible for that.

I looked at all my files in my XLSTART folder: The macros that they contain that have names auto_open etc. But I cannot find the culprit.

Is this a setting in Excel perhaps? Please help!

Comment: No, definitely it's not a setting in Excel. Please try to disable macros and then try enable one by one / have a closer look / debug. Based on your description it's not really possible to help more.

Comment: You were right. It was inside an add-in to which I don't have the password, created by a different department in our company. That's why I didn't see it. Thanks.